# Scala Slick how can I convert a select query to Json

Tags: json, scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0

I am using slick 3.1.1 and haven't been able to figure out how I can convert a query in Json. I have this simple query that returns a fullname

```
def listfollowing() = Action {

    val setup = DBIO.seq(
      sql"""select p.fullname from profiles p join relations r on(p.id=r.following) where r.me=32;""".as[(String)]
    )
    val setupFuture = db.run(setup)


    Ok(Json.toJson(setupFuture.toString))


  }
```

Which simply gives of this result

> "scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise@6a3903"

Any suggestions would be great

Here some additional information:

```
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.libs.json.{Json, JsValue}
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}
import slick.dbio.DBIO
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
import play.api.data.Forms._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  val db= Database.forConfig("database")
  try {
    // ...
  } finally db.close
```

I connect to slick as follows

```
database {
  dataSourceClass = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
  properties = {
    databaseName = "mydbname"
    user = "user"
    password = "password"
  }
  numThreads = 10

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`setupFuture` in your case is a `Future`, which means it (may) hold a value in the future. To get "inside" a `Future`, you will want to `.map` on it (if you're more familiar with the frontend world, this is similar to Javascript `Promise`s / `.then`). The body of the `map` will run when the future's value is available.

Here's an implementation that will return real data:

```
def listfollowing() = Action.async {
  val setup = DBIO.seq(
    sql"""select p.fullname from profiles p join relations r on(p.id=r.following) where r.me=32;""".as[String]
  )
  db.run(setup).map { result =>
    Ok(Json.toJson(result.toString))
  }
}
```

Take special note of `Action.async`.

Comment: Oh ok I just ran it and I have a few questions. If I put in the code just like that I get an error on the db.run(setup) which is: Cannot find an implicit ExecutionContext. You might pass
 an (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) parameter to your method
 or import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global. Then i import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global and it compiles but I get another error: IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize ExecutionContext; AsyncExecutor already shut down . I will post my setup above